# more than 98% of ram usage by svchost

Tags: hard-drive, memory

Recently I am facing some problem that I can't understand the reason.I start my computer and after a few minutes ram usage goes up to 98% only svchost use it.I don't know what to do.To overcome the problem I have recently formated my HDD and reinstall windows but the problem occurs the same.Can any one tell me what should I do to overcome this problem

Comment: Does it stay that way forever? It's likely a background process doing something important.

Comment: No It don't stay long time.But I have never seen like this before.Is my hard disk life is degrading because when I disclosed this matter to an computer expert he said that the problem occurred for my hardisk  as it isn't in a stable condition so process loads to Ram to execute and it exceed the usage of Ram.

Comment: I can't say for certain without more information about which svchost is running. When the process is using 98% RAM, you can open the Resource Monitor from Task Manager and check which service is using the RAM in the Memory tab. It will be named something like `svchost.exe (imgsvc)`.

Comment: Sir,according to your comment I have opened the task manager and saw the svchost.exe(secsvcs) it takes the whole ram usage and I want to add that ram usage of 98% occurs 2-3 times in a day.

Comment: That would be Windows Defender. It's probably running a scan. If you have another security software, you can turn it off. Otherwise, it's likely struggling to scan a large file.

Comment: imgsvc can be the WIA service to support picture scanning. Do you have a scanner attached to your device?

Comment: No sir I don't have any scanner device.It just happened when I formated my computer twice in a day.Though I know that today's harddisk is SSD but that problem is unprecedented to me.I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Is the only reason you think you need to do something the advice you got from that "expert"? Are you sure you have an actual problem?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk which als runs since Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **VirtualAlloc usage, **Resident Analysis** and click **start** Now capture 2-3 minutes of the memory usage grow and click on **Save** to store the report into an ETL file. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Could you write the version of Windows you use and the amount of RAM you have got on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your RAM to be used, take it out of your machine. If you have an actual performance problem, tell us what it is.

Modern operating systems go out of their way to use as much RAM as possible. Any RAM not used is opportunity forever lost. A machine with 4GB of RAM can't use 2GB today so it can use 6GB tomorrow. RAM can't be saved for later.

If you're thinking "I want my RAM free now so I can use it later", get that nonsense out of your head. Using RAM now doesn't stop you from also using it later. There's no tradeoff here -- there's no reason not to use as much RAM as possible. You've got it, use it.

Comment: That's a horrible answer.  OP has an issue of an instance of svchost running and sucking up resources.  This happens.  And its a pain to fix.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths ignore all answers from him regarding memory usage. He repeats his "memory usage is good" all the time.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths The resources that are being sucked up are "use it or lose it" resources. Memory usage *is* good. Memory that's not used provides no benefit whatsoever, it's no better than memory sitting on a shelf. I repeat it because the myth that usage is bad persists despite being thoroughly refuted over and over. (He may have a real problem, but if so, all he's done is described what might be a clue to it.)

Comment: Yeah, I get it.  But clearly you've never dealt with an issue like this before.  I have.  Its not easy to troubleshoot.  This shouldn't be happening.  But keep on repeating the meme, it's still not an answer to the OP's problem.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths The OP hasn't mentioned a problem. He hasn't said he has excessive disk I/O, poor performance, or anything else. I have worked on issues, but this isn't one.

Comment: Then you can't read very well and lack comprehension skills.  He doesn't need excessive disk I/O, poor performance is going to be happening because RAM usage is 98% from some rogue svchost.  Oh, look, there's the problem.  He doesn't know what's causing it.  Therein lies the issue.  RAM usage shouldn't be pegging out at 98% or 100%.  As YOU said, you haven't had an issue like this.

Comment: RAM usage pegging out at very close to 100% is absolutely normal on modern operating systems. I'm on a Windows machine with 8GB right now, doing practically nothing, and less than 1GB is unused. I haven't had an issue like this because THIS IS NOT AN ISSUE. He has reported absolutely nothing that is not normal.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths **stop discussing with this troll**, he will never understand your issue. reboot Windows, capture a trace (2-3 minutes) of the memory usage grow and I can tell what is going on

Comment: A little harsh but absolutely true. There isn't even a questionmark in OPs "question" so why bothering to get a possible explanation for this behavior if there are no problematic symptoms? If he wants to know why svchost can take up to 98% RAM he should talk to one of the programmers ;)